# Teamrender like Cinema 4D

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine

Is there a piece of software (as far as I can see it's not built in) that mimics the behaviour of C4D teamrender?

All solutions I've found for private rendering on multiple devices is more of a hack and sharing files back and forth.

I'm looking for a solution just like it works in C4D. I set up the teamrender on all my devices I want, hit render on my main computer and the program itself splits the image into multiple tiles and gives each computer a specific amount of tiles to render and combine the endresult on the main pc. So it "feels like" it's rendered on one pc without any trouble.

Comment: there is an explanation here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y3EcpkwLCFI but i don't know C4D and it sounds like you are search for a oneclick - solution and i fear this is only possible with a paid add-on

Comment: I mean, even a paid add-on would be an option. But I couldn't find anything like this...
In C4D you set it up once, hit render and you can see while it's rendering in different colors what computer renders what tile and the end result is the same just as it would be when rendered on one computer. I don't need the same look, just something simple without a server I have to set up first or push files to other machines every time I want to render.